# How to disable code inspection in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image]

On line 2 and 3 there are highlights on "Node" and "label." How do I remove these highlights? The translucent highlight variables are sometimes not visible.

Comment: It is due to suggestions from idea, you can change color for suggestions.

Comment: Most colors can be changed in `Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA warns the developer about possible problems in the code this way. You can configure it manually in **(Settings / Preferences (on macOS) | Editor | Inspection)** section or perform the [Intention action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html#apply-intention-actions) to disable/change them:

[image]

See the corresponding [documentation page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html) for more details.

The warning color can be changed in **(Settings / Preferences (on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Errors and Warnings)** section.